# 2 dataframe column values not working in where clause

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val creation_timestamp = df.groupBy().agg(min($"userCreation_timestamp").alias("ts")).col("ts")

df.filter(col("userCreation_timestamp").cast("timestamp") >= creation_timestamp).show()
or
df.where(col("userCreation_timestamp").cast("timestamp") >= creation_timestamp).show()
```

When running the code above to show the data, I obtain the following exception:

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s).`

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) ts#1658 missing from id#2,userCreation_timestamp#8,firstname#31 in operator !Filter (cast(userCreation_timestamp#8 as timestamp) >= ts#1658).;;
!Filter (cast(userCreation_timestamp#8 as timestamp) >= ts#1658)
+- Relation[id#02,userCreation_timestamp#8, 26 more fields] parquet

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:172)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:3306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1463)
  ... 49 elided
```

```
df.where(col("userCreation_timestamp").cast("timestamp") >= "2022-03-11 18:36:48").show()
```

with literal value in where clause, code is working fine but when using dataframe then it is getting failed

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you're not passing the value of the `ts` column in your filter condition, but the column itself. As the `ts` column does not exist in `df` dataframe, you get a `AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) ts#1658 missing` exception.

If you want to pass the value of the column, you need to retrieve the first row of your aggregated dataframe, then retrieve the timestamp value in this row, and finally use `lit` to pass it to your condition:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{min, lit, col}

val creation_timestamp = df.agg(min($"userCreation_timestamp")).head().getTimestamp(0)

df.filter(col("userCreation_timestamp").cast("timestamp") >= lit(creation_timestamp)).show()
```